# Data constraint rejects all new entries

Tags: excel, validation

`COUNTIF($A$2:$A$1048576; A2)=1` is a rule I've defined in `Data validation -> custom`. The idea is to reject each new entry that already exists in the table. Unfortunately, no matter what I add to the table, it is rejected, even if its value in row column A is not already existing in another entry.

What's the problem here?

[image: rulre applies to:]

[image]

[image: Allows duplicate rows]

Comment: You don't show row numbers on the screenshot, but probably you need to change A2 to A1 in your formula or change active cell (it should be address of active cell when you open data validation window)

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$1048576,A2)=1
```

rather than:

```
COUNTIF($A$2:$A$1048576,A2)=1
```

[image]

Then copy cell **A2** downwards.

Comment: I did that, but now it just accepts everything, even duplicate entries.

Comment: @Sandi  You may need ***;***